# How to prevent a service from terminating?

Tags: java, android, android-service

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {
private TextView mTextView;
private static MainActivity instance;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    // Enables Always-on
    setAmbientEnabled();

    final TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (text.getText().toString().equals("Started")) {
                text.setText("Stoped");
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,service.class));
            } else {
                text.setText("Started");
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,service.class));
            }
        }
    });
}

public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void showToast(String toastMsg){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**Service.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.MainThread;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class service extends Service {
private boolean started = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("serviceTest", "Service started by user.");
    start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    //Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("serviceTest", "Service destroyed by user.");
    stop();

    super.onDestroy();
}




private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(started) {
            start();
        }

        Log.i("serviceTest", "ServiceCalled!");
    }
};

public void start() {
    if(timer != null) {
        return;
    }
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 10000);
}

public void stop() {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}
}
```

The code runs okay for about 13 or 14 times (i.e. the timer keeps on running for about 13 or 14 times) but suddenly the service stops and onDestroy is called.
Also, during debugging, I have noticed one strange condition: *If I delete/comment the onDestroy() method form the code then the service runs always. It never closes on its own. (it only closes upon user input, which is fine)*

Please suggest a solution so that the services do not get killed/ destroyed. Or if the OS/ System kills it, then the service starts again on its own.

Thnx

Comment: You should use Jobservice instead of service for android version higher that 7.0

Comment: Unrelated: class names should go UpperCamelCase in Java. **s**ervice is not only violating that rule, it is also a name that says **nothing** about the code in it. Use names that **talk** to the reader. Names communicate intent. "service" communicates nothing.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica NOTED and thnx

Answer (score 1):

You will have to turn that background service into a foreground service, because of the limitations called Background Execution Limits that started from android Oreo.

Please check out this link for more better understanding: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: Thanks Alex. Will post my results once I use JobService